# Multiple Function Call - Public Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get my Public Sub to make a call against two functions, each creating different pivot tables off of the same data sheet. I know that both of my functions work independently, but I keep getting an "application defined or object defined error" when I combine them in to a single sub.

The macro below does execute the first function and creates the intended pivot table. It just stops when it gets to the second function and provides me with the application or object defined error mentioned above. I have independently defined each function so I am not sure why I am getting an issue.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunPivots()
Call BuildPivot1("Travel Payment Data by Employee")
Call BuildPivot2("Travel Payment Data by Acct Dim")

End Sub

Function BuildPivot1(paramSheet As String)
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
Dim FinalRow            As Long
Dim DataSheet           As String
Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
Dim PvtFld              As PivotField
Dim DataRng             As Range
Dim TableDest           As Range
Dim ws                  As Worksheet

 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name Like "*SQL" & "*" Then
        '~~> This check is required to ensure that you don't get an error
        '~~> if there is only one sheet left and it matches the delete criteria
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count = 1 Then
            MsgBox "There is only one sheet left and you cannot delete it"
        Else
            '~~> This is required to supress the dialog box which excel shows
            '~~> When you delete a sheet. Remove it if you want to see the
            '~~~> Dialog Box
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End If
Next

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

DataSheet = "Export Worksheet"
' set data range for Pivot Table
 Set DataRng = Sheets(DataSheet).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(FinalRow, 15))

' check if worksheet exists
Dim currws As Worksheet
For Each currws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If currws.Name = paramSheet Then
        Set ws = Worksheets(paramSheet)
        Exit For
    End If
Next currws

' create new worksheet if does not exist
If ws Is Nothing Then
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    ws.Name = paramSheet
End If

' set range for Pivot table placement
Set TableDest = Sheets(paramSheet).Cells(1, 1)

' create pivot cache
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
          SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
          SourceData:=DataRng, _
          Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

'check if "PivotTable4" Pivot Table exists
Dim currpvt As PivotTable
For Each currpvt In ws.PivotTables
    If currpvt.Name = "PivotTable4" Then
        Set PvtTbl = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable4")
        Exit For
    End If
Next currpvt

' create new pivot table if does not exist
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then
    Set PvtTbl = PvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=TableDest, _
        TableName:="PivotTable4")
End If

With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Security Org")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Fiscal Month")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Budget Org")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Vendor Name")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 4
End With
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Fiscal Year")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 5
End With
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Fiscal Year")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With

Range("B:E").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
Range("B1").Select
PvtTbl.CompactLayoutColumnHeader = _
    "Fiscal Year"
Range("A2").Select
PvtTbl.CompactLayoutRowHeader = _
    "Security Org and Vendor"
Range("G8").Select

' Add data field if does not exist
On Error Resume Next
PvtTbl.AddDataField PvtTbl.PivotFields("Dollar Amount"), "Sum of Dollar Amount", xlSum
PvtTbl.PivotFields("Budget Org").ShowDetail = _
    False
Exit Function

ErrHandle:
MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
Exit Function
End Function

Function BuildPivot2(paramSheet As String)
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
Dim FinalRow            As Long
Dim DataSheet           As String
Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
Dim PvtFld              As PivotField
Dim DataRng             As Range
Dim TableDest           As Range
Dim ws                  As Worksheet

 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name Like "*SQL" & "*" Then
        '~~> This check is required to ensure that you don't get an error
        '~~> if there is only one sheet left and it matches the delete criteria
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count = 1 Then
            MsgBox "There is only one sheet left and you cannot delete it"
        Else
            '~~> This is required to supress the dialog box which excel shows
            '~~> When you delete a sheet. Remove it if you want to see the
            '~~~> Dialog Box
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End If
Next

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

DataSheet = "Export Worksheet"
' set data range for Pivot Table
DataSheet = "Export Worksheet"
' set data range for Pivot Table
With Sheets(DataSheet)
    Set DataRng = .Range(Cells(1, 1), .Cells(FinalRow, 15))
End With

' check if worksheet exists
Dim currws As Worksheet
For Each currws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If currws.Name = paramSheet Then
        Set ws = Worksheets(paramSheet)
        Exit For
    End If
Next currws

' create new worksheet if does not exist
If ws Is Nothing Then
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    ws.Name = paramSheet
End If

' set range for Pivot table placement
Set TableDest = Sheets(paramSheet).Cells(1, 1)

' create pivot cache
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
          SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
          SourceData:=DataRng, _
          Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

'check if "PivotTable4" Pivot Table exists
Dim currpvt As PivotTable
For Each currpvt In ws.PivotTables
    If currpvt.Name = "PivotTable4" Then
        Set PvtTbl = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable4")
        Exit For
    End If
Next currpvt

' create new pivot table if does not exist
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then
    Set PvtTbl = PvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=TableDest, _
        TableName:="PivotTable4")
End If

With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Fiscal Year")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Fund")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Budget Org")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Cost Org")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With

Range("B:E").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
Range("B1").Select
PvtTbl.CompactLayoutColumnHeader = _
    "Fiscal Year"
Range("A2").Select
PvtTbl.CompactLayoutRowHeader = _
    "Security Org and Vendor"
Range("G8").Select

' Add data field if does not exist
On Error Resume Next
PvtTbl.AddDataField PvtTbl.PivotFields("Dollar Amount"), "Sum of Dollar Amount", xlSum
PvtTbl.PivotFields("Budget Org").ShowDetail = _
    False
Exit Function

ErrHandle:
MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Which line throws the error?

Comment: just getting a 1004 error, it isn't pointing me to a line

Comment: You need to make sure all of your Cells() and Range() calls are qualified with a worksheet object

Comment: Both Pivot tables are using the same worksheet to build off of. The ranges/cells haven't changed.

Comment: Are the involved sheets (data sheet and pivot sheet) in the same workbook? If yes, is it to be the workbook where the macro resides in?

Comment: yes everything should reside in the same workbook. datasheet and pivot sheet reside in the workbook.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure all of your Cells() and Range() calls are qualified with a worksheet object. For example:

```
Set DataRng = Sheets(DataSheet).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(FinalRow, 15))
```

will fail if the `DataSheet` worksheet is not the activesheet.

Fix like this:

```
With Sheets(DataSheet)
    Set DataRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(FinalRow, 15))
End With
```

Comment: Got pretty hopeful, but no luck. Still getting the same application defined or object defined error.

Comment: Would help to update your question with the updated code.

Comment: DataSheet = "Export Worksheet"
    ' set data range for Pivot Table
    With Sheets(DataSheet)
        Set DataRng = .Range(Cells(1, 1), .Cells(FinalRow, 15))
    End With
    I updated the second function with the code above. Still getting the same error. I also tried in both functions and it doesn't run.